# Вопрос правильного позиционирования элементов относительно z-index

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы был вот такой эффект с тенью, но кнопки можно было выбирать?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.forlabels {
position: relative;
z-index: -1
}

.forlabels-section {
  position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    box-shadow: -12px 0 10px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}

.tab--element {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F1F4F9;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-right: 4px solid #fff;
}
.tab--element:last-child {
border: none;
border-right: 4px solid #fff;
}

.nav-element {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F1F4F9;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.tab--checked,
.tab--element:hover,
.nav-element:hover {
  background: #1DB061;
  border-bottom-color: #1DB061;
  border-right: 4px solid #17874B;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
          transition: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="forlabels-section">
    <div class="forlabels">

      <label for="sect-1" class="tab--element tab--checked">Демонтаж</label>

      <label for="sect-2" class="tab--element">Стены</label>

      <label for="sect-3" class="tab--element">Потолки</label>

      <label for="sect-4" class="tab--element">Полы</label>

   <label for="sect-5" class="tab--element">Двери и проёмы</label>

   <label for="sect-6" class="tab--element">Электромонтажные работы</label>

   <label for="sect-7" class="tab--element">Сантехнические работы</label>

   <label for="sect-8" class="tab--element">Вентиляция</label>

   <label for="sect-9" class="tab--element">Дополнительные расходы</label>

</div><!--forlabels-->
    </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/8ej72j39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}
.forlabels {
  position: relative;
}
.forlabels-section {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: -12px 0 10px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset;
}
[id^=sect-] {
  display: none;
}
[id^=sect-] + label {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F1F4F9;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
}
[id^=sect-]:checked + label {
  background: #1DB061;
  border-bottom-color: #1DB061;
  border-right: 4px solid #17874B;
  color: #fff;
}
[id^=sect-] + label ~ [id^=tab-content-] {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#sect-1:checked + label ~ #tab-content-1,
#sect-2:checked + label ~ #tab-content-2,
#sect-3:checked + label ~ #tab-content-3,
#sect-4:checked + label ~ #tab-content-4,
#sect-5:checked + label ~ #tab-content-5,
#sect-6:checked + label ~ #tab-content-6,
#sect-7:checked + label ~ #tab-content-7,
#sect-8:checked + label ~ #tab-content-8,
#sect-9:checked + label ~ #tab-content-9 {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="forlabels-section">
  <div class="forlabels">

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-1" />
    <label for="sect-1" class="tab--element tab--checked">Демонтаж</label>
    <div id="tab-content-1">tab-content 1</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-2" />
    <label for="sect-2" class="tab--element">Стены</label>
    <div id="tab-content-2">tab-content 2</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-3" />
    <label for="sect-3" class="tab--element">Потолки</label>
    <div id="tab-content-3">tab-content 3</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-4" />
    <label for="sect-4" class="tab--element">Полы</label>
    <div id="tab-content-4">tab-content 4</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-5" />
    <label for="sect-5" class="tab--element">Двери и проёмы</label>
    <div id="tab-content-5">tab-content 5</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-6" />
    <label for="sect-6" class="tab--element">Электромонтажные работы</label>
    <div id="tab-content-6">tab-content 6</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-7" />
    <label for="sect-7" class="tab--element">Сантехнические работы</label>
    <div id="tab-content-7">tab-content 7</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-8" />
    <label for="sect-8" class="tab--element">Вентиляция</label>
    <div id="tab-content-8">tab-content 8</div>

    <input type="radio" name="tab" id="sect-9" />
    <label for="sect-9" class="tab--element">Дополнительные расходы</label>
    <div id="tab-content-9">tab-content 9</div>
  </div>
  <!--forlabels-->
</div>
```